# Source Code build of MacPGP2 fails with home-brew/ruby build error a la git hub

Tags: ruby, git, homebrew

I want to build the source distribution of the GPG Suite, in this case, just the MacPGP2 portion.

I went to the GPG Suite site, grabbed the copy-lefted source, and read thru a lot of release notes, read me files, and then realized the Readme.md file describes how to do the build right out of git-hub, so I figured I'd simply do that with the following sequence:

```
git clone https://github.com/GPGTools/MacGPG2.git
cd MacGPG2
git submodule init
git submodule update
make
```

This crapped out.

I narrowed the problem down to a hard-coded path to the wrong ruby interpreter in the top line of a very brew config file:

```
.../MacGPG2/build/homebrew/Library/brew.rb
```

which points to a version of ruby that is not installed on my Mac, as far as I know:

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -W0
```

I played around and patched this config file to point to a known ruby, but that merely exposed some ruby coding errors further along in the MacPGP2 ruby source.  I abandoned trying to patch homebrew.

At this point, it looks like a build.sh script constructs or grabs a homebrew config file that points to a very wrong hardcoded place, for my case.  I don't know how to fix this or whom to notify about this problem.

So, I decided to toss this out there, here. So to speak.

Thanks.

Here is the git sequence:

[git sequence to generate a gpg suite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYdQc.png)